# Why restify not have its own plugin for support cookies?

Tags: node.js, cookies, plugins, restify

I like [restify](https://github.com/restify/node-restify), it has a lot of fans, but why it does not have [its own plugin](https://github.com/restify/plugins) for support cookies?

Maybe I do not know something, and when using REST-architecture did not need to use cookies? Perhaps for this purpose using a different approach? Is it possible that there is already a popular module Node.js, which can be easily integrated with restify?

Answer (score 6):

There is a module for adding cookies to [restify](https://github.com/restify/node-restify).  It is called [restify-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/restify-cookies).

Incidentally, you don't need this module to use cookies.  Since cookies are just headers you can add them by using res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "cookie value;") and you can access them by using req.header("Cookie").

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I saw this plug-in, but it seems he is not popular. Now I try to use your advice.